# Capybara not working with x-editable forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to test my inline editable elements using capybara and poltergeist, on Rails 4, Bootstrap 3, and Boostrap-editable-rails 0.0.7, and following the examples in [the x-editable docs](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#select). Capybara seems to click on the elements but their conversion to the form element never takes place. It works fine when going through the UI in dev mode.

```
<a class="edit_form" id="edit-note-category-<%= jira.id %>" href="#" data-type="select" 
    data-source="<%=@note_categories%>" data-value="<%=note.note_category.try(:id) %>" 
    data-resource="note" data-name="note_category_id" data-pk="<%=note.id%>" 
    data-url="/correct/path">
</a>

# CUCUMBER STEP DEFINITIONS
When(/^I click the element for the (.*?)$/) do |element|  
    element = element.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')  
    elem_id = "#edit-#{element}-#{@jira.id}"  
    find(elem_id).trigger('click')  
end

When(/^I change the note's category to "(.*?)"$/) do |category_name|
    select category_name
end
```

The test for this fails with an ElementNotFound exception when trying to select the category name. The html in dev mode shows a select is created after the element is clicked, but a screenshot mid-test after the same action shows no such select element.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time since you asked this question, but I stumbled on this when experiencing what is probably the same issue. I had setup X-Editable to make a PATCH request when updating a field. This worked fine in production/development but when we wanted to add a feature spec for it we had difficulty. I tested it using the selenium driver, that worked too. The issue was clearly with using Poltergeist.

It turns out, there is currently a bug with PhantomJS (the underlying engine for Poltergeist) with making PATCH requests (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11384). While it would be nice to have and more semantic, my solution was to change the request to a PUT.

Something like this:

```
function enableInlineEditable() {
  $('.inline-editable').editable({
    ajaxOptions: { type: 'PUT' },
  });
}
```